# Failure during standard install of Reason on MacOs (updated by author)

Tags: ocaml, reason

I'm following the install procedure at https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/installation.
(The MacOs CLI tools provided by Xcode have been installed.)
The specified commands to install Reason and run a hello world test are:

```
    npm install -g esy
    git clone https://github.com/esy-ocaml/hello-reason.git
    cd hello-reason
    esy 
    esy x Hello
```

The 4th step (the "esy" command fails with the following output:

```
info esy 0.6.12 (using package.json)
info fetching: done                                 
info installing: done                                          
info building @esy-ocaml/substs@0.0.1@d41d8cd9
info building ocaml@4.12.0@d41d8cd9
info building @esy-ocaml/substs@0.0.1@d41d8cd9: done
info building @opam/base-unix@opam:base@87d0b2eb
info building @opam/base-threads@opam:base@36803084
info building @opam/base-threads@opam:base@36803084: done
info building @opam/base-unix@opam:base@87d0b2eb: done
error: build failed with exit code: 1
  build log:
    # esy-build-package: building: ocaml@4.12.0
    # esy-build-package: pwd: /Users/sbeisner/.esy/3/b/ocaml-4.12.0-44d44425
    # esy-build-package: running: './esy-configure' '--disable-cfi' '--prefix' '/Users/sbeisner/.esy/3_______________________________________________________________/s/ocaml-4.12.0-44d44425'
    [esy-configure] Detected OSX / Linux environment
    configure: Configuring OCaml version 4.12.0
    checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
    checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
    checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
    checking for ld... ld
    checking how to print strings... printf
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... no
    configure: error: in `/Users/sbeisner/.esy/3/b/ocaml-4.12.0-44d44425':
    configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
    See `config.log' for more details
    error: command failed: './esy-configure' '--disable-cfi' '--prefix' '/Users/sbeisner/.esy/3_______________________________________________________________/s/ocaml-4.12.0-44d44425' (exited with 77)
    esy-build-package: exiting with errors above...
    
  building ocaml@4.12.0
esy: exiting due to errors above
```

I can see that the C compiler is present:

```
    gcc --version
```

reports:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Can someone point me to what I'm missing or overlooking?
Thanks.

UPDATED:

I found that the problem above is due to the fact that Apple symbolically links "gcc" to the clang compiler that Apple distributes.  (*An incredibly irresponsible idea!*) After installing the real gcc (via homebrew) most of the build kicked off by the "esy" command runs OK, UNTIL, (near the end?) it get errors trying to create files in /var/folders/mt/.....

So I'm stuck again.  It appears, based on the kinds of errors above that the standard install procedure has not been tested on MacOS.
Disappointing!!!

Please, if you have successfully installed Reason on MacOs, please let me know how you did it?  Thanks!

Comment: `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables` This seems to be the important line. Do you have permission to create files in the directory you're trying to build in?

Comment: Also worth a look:  `checking whether the C compiler works... no`

Comment: You may need to modify permissions on /var/folders/mt

Comment: yes... the problems I mentioned in the original failure were fixed by swapping from Apple's to the *real* gcc.     The build still fails... on "failure to create file" errors.